# OProfile on android

Tags: android, linux-kernel, profiling, oprofile

Has anybody used OProfile tool on android...If you are able to profile please provide the basic steps and any other configuration or setup in order to do that...

Regards,
Bharat Pawar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [this very effective method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024). It works just fine on Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

oprofile is said to be supported in some htc devices :

http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/a722fde26c5330ca