# Oprofile success on android?

Tags: android, performance, perf, oprofile

I was wondering, has anyone managed to successfully configure oprofile for Android? Specifically, to measure hardware counter events (NOT the standard oprofile timer-interrupt based mode).

If so, what model phone did you use, and which kernel version/branch?

This post ([OProfile on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354349/oprofile-on-android)) sort of addresses my question, but it only lists one success story for oprofile on Andriod.  In particular, I'm looking to see if anyone knows of a model or architecture which has a lot of built-in support for oprofile (my experience is that OMAP4 processors, for example, are very hard to build oprofile for).

I'd also be interested if anyone got the perf profiler working, as an alternative.

Comment: I never played with oprofile on Android but I recently installed perf on some smartphones. That works quite well except there are some limitations: hardware (PMU) not fully supported, strange behaviours of the tool itself (always the same shared objects reported, help not working with some commands, problem to monitor only one process, ...). I suggest you have a look at perf, that is a kind of successor to oprofile (easier to use, more coherent, ...).

Comment: @amigadev, I have indeed looked at perf. Unfortunately, I just can't get it to build. Some guides/posts out there say that the perf binary should just build with the Android source tree: that isn't the case for me. And trying to run "make" in the perf directory of the source tree runs into countless compilation errors. How did you manage to get perf to build? Is there some kernel/build config options I'm missing out on?

Comment: Initially, I also failed trying to build perf with its own makefile if the perf directory. But I succeeded added "perf" in the list of PRODUCT_PACKAGES in "build/target/product/full_base.mk" that we build.